# UINavigationController and UISplitviewController

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am fairly new to iOS programming using MonoTouch. I am trying to build an application for iPad and have some questions.

How can I have both UINavigationController and UISplitviewController with in an application?

When the application launches, I am displaying a UINavigationController based view. From that screen, Users can navigate to different views and one of them needs to be based on UISplitviewController.

I am not sure how to do this?

Also, how can I customize the table view in the SplitViewController (MasterList). I like to display the table in grouped style.

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not related to Monotouch per se, as it is a more generic question.

In general you can combine your views in any way you like, any UIViewController has a View property, if you need to have a SplitViewController just as one of the view in your view stack on NavigationController, lets go for that, use the PushViewController on the UINavigationController and give it the instance of you UISplitViewController derived class.

But must be said it is usually used the otherway round. Sample can be the mail application on the iPad, where you have the UISplitViewController as the top most view and in its "left part" there is a UINavigationController with the mail accounts that you can drill down through.

Have fun with it and happy coding your app!
@sichy